# Single set of feature files for both Android and iOS

Tags: xamarin, calabash, xamarin.forms, calabash-ios, calabash-android

How can I go about sharing my feature files between iOS and Android under Xamarin Forms? I don't see the reason to create multiple feature directories when I am testing a single UI codebase?

What is the recommended approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet is to use the Page Object pattern for testing. I haven't tried it on Xamarin.Forms specifically, but in theory that shouldn't matter. The [TaskyPro-Calabash](https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples/tree/master/TaskyPro-Calabash) project is an example of this. It's discuss a bit in the [Introducing the Page Object Pattern section](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/calabash/creating-calabash-tests/#Introducing_the_Page_Object_Pattern) of [Creating Calabash Tests](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/calabash/creating-calabash-tests/).

Basically, the idea is to a Page class for each screen that knows how to manipulate the screen and holds the Calabash queries. The Page is where the platform specific knowledge lives and will share a common set of methods between Android and iOS. The step definitions will interact with the screen via the Page object. The feature then, in turn, will use the step definitions.

Comment: Thanks Tom. This seems to be the right approach. I missed this walkthrough.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly , its not a good approach to create multiple feature directories when you testing a single UI code-base . Specially when tool you are using supports cross-platform as Calabash supports .

You can keep a common Features & step-definitions across the platform . however you have to mention platform path in cucumber profile , that is your cucumber.yml file

Please go through the example for more details : [Calabash X-platform example](https://github.com/calabash/x-platform-example/tree/master/config)

If you still face any difficulty please comment below . or if it helps make this answer as useful